# Why do I get undefined variable error in Yii controller?

Tags: php, yii

I get `Undefined variable: user` error in my controller:

And this is my **controller**:

```
public function actionduration()
{
    if (isset($_POST['W'])&&isset($_POST['Nodelist']))
    {
        $user = Sensor::model()->Week();
    }
    else if (isset($_POST['M'])&&isset($_POST['Nodelist']))
    {
        $user = Sensor::model()->Month();
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['S'])&&isset($_POST['Nodelist']))
    {
        $user = Sensor::model()->Six();
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['Y'])&&isset($_POST['Nodelist']))
    {
        $user = Sensor::model()->Year();
    }
    //print_r($user);

    $this->layout='main2';
    //$layout='//layouts/main1';
    $this->render('edit1', array('user'=>$user));
}
```

Comment: It would be good to post here your complete code. And `$user` is undefined, because you did not define `$user` in your controller.

Comment: but i am not able put all code here , i got error ,

Comment: user is already i had used in other controller action

Comment: I think there is a big lack of knowledge. You should first learn the basics. If you defined a variable in a function, it is only available in this function as long as it is not a class variable or global variable.

Comment: Check if your `$_POST` meets your `if` conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `$user` in starting.As your $user is not getting set in any if else statement.

Try this:

```
public function actionduration()
{
  $user=""; 
  $this->layout='main2';
 if (isset($_POST['W'])&&isset($_POST['Nodelist']))
  {
    $user = Sensor::model()->Week();
   }
else if (isset($_POST['M'])&&isset($_POST['Nodelist']))
{
    $user = Sensor::model()->Month();
}
else if(isset($_POST['S'])&&isset($_POST['Nodelist']))
{
    $user = Sensor::model()->Six();
}
else if(isset($_POST['Y'])&&isset($_POST['Nodelist']))
{
    $user = Sensor::model()->Year();
}

$this->render('edit1', array('user'=>$user));
}
```

Or You Can create one more else in last :

```
public function actionduration()
{
if (isset($_POST['W'])&&isset($_POST['Nodelist']))
{
    $user = Sensor::model()->Week();
}
else if (isset($_POST['M'])&&isset($_POST['Nodelist']))
{
    $user = Sensor::model()->Month();
}
else if(isset($_POST['S'])&&isset($_POST['Nodelist']))
{
    $user = Sensor::model()->Six();
}
else if(isset($_POST['Y'])&&isset($_POST['Nodelist']))
{
    $user = Sensor::model()->Year();
}
else
{
   $user=""; 
 }
//print_r($user);

$this->layout='main2';
//$layout='//layouts/main1';
$this->render('edit1', array('user'=>$user));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This means your code is not initializing $user. Do a test to check if any of the if conditions are returning true. Looks like they all return false.